# How to get the real decrypted text

Tags: encryption

In this code , How to get the O/P as India . I am getting the encrypted result but how to get the real output.

```
<?php

 $xyz='India';

 $md=md5($xyz);

 $abc=base64_encode($md);

 echo $base=base64_decode($abc);

?>
```

I am getting the O/P as 7d31e0da1ab99fe8b08a22118e2f402b

but i want the O/P as India , How to get it please help.

Comment: You can't. Hashing functions are one-way. They aren't encryption.

Comment: md5 is for hashing, base64 for encoding... you have no encryption here...

Comment: You are reversing only the base64 encoding, not the md5 operation (which you can't reverse).

Comment: So how to do the reverse way decryption .....

Comment: @DeeptimanPattnaik: You aren't doing encryption in the first place, so there is no decryption.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reverse MD5. Thats why MD5 is often used as password hashing since you can only bruteforce it to get the decrypted value.

Comment: It's not exactly true that you can only bruteforce MD5. It has long been considered cryptographically broken and shouldn't be used to hash passwords.